# Storing Form Data in SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I am trying to design an SQL Database to build survey forms for instance:

[image: Database]

```
Many lead_has_survey can be related to many surveys 
A survey can be related to many survey_fields (The name of the field)
A field can be related to many different options (Radio buttons/Select boxes)
```

The above diagram works fine for storing only multiple choice options but where do I store values that are just plain text and could equal anything? The data for each survey has to relate back to lead_has_survey.

With the above I am left with a useless foreign key in leads_has_survey_has_survey_field_value_options if the value ddoesnt have a predefined option in survey_field_value_options. This is where I am stuck, what can I do to make this work so I can store both selectbox / radio options and unknown text values?

Comment: A table with available answers would be helpful.

Comment: Available answers could be anything they would be created per individual survey stored in fields_options

Comment: In that case, while it would have a primary key, what is the purpose of the foreign key?

Comment: To relate it to a particular field. For instance, the field could be 'Do you like our service?' And there could be nth amount of options related to that field. There can also be many different survey forms.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have updated the question, I hope this now explains what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create multiple tables.

eg.  one for predefined values, one for surveys and the last one for links between them.

```
survey:
    -id
    -other attributes(such as name)..
predefined1:
    -id
    -textvalue
    -other attributes(description etc.)
links(predefined1):
    -survey_id
    -predef_id
```

I hope I understood the problem.